# Regular Expression: 0-9 A-Z a-z or any of these '!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to regex string myString to only have:

- 0-9
- A-Z or a-z
- any of these characters '!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.

This is my code line:

```
new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]").IsMatch(myString);
```

So far I have `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and this works fine for the first two listitems.
Currently tearing my hair out (and it's so nice I want to keep it) over metacharacters and getting nowhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Dave

Comment: What is the problem? Did you escape them?

Comment: I have tried escaping them with \ and get unrecognised sequence at run time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi there If you want only the listed characters in your string it is very simple.but you need to match beginning an end of line

```
new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9'!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]*$").IsMatch(myString);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9'!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]"
```

check that ("-") minus sign be the last char in a `[]` sequence

Answer (score 2):

Meta characters are fine between brackets, as long as you escape the significant ones. Moreover the dash MUST be the last one of your sequence.

```
new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9'!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]").IsMatch(myString);
```

Comment: Nope.  The . alllows any character so that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var re = "[a-zA-Z0-9" +  Regex.Escape("'!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.") + "]";
```

Comment: `Regex.Escape` isn't safe in a character class - it doesn't escape `-` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx . It will also escape characters that don't need it, but that's OK.